# Why is our Office 365 add-in flagged by Outlook 2013 as "not responding"?

Tags: office365, office-js, office365api, outlook-2013, outlook-web-addins

One of our users is experiencing this error in Outlook 2013 "[this app is not responding](https://www.evernote.com/l/AGPHHe40xBpCEZtSmz1kl2GdrrX0vrI8DOs)".

We can't really re-produce the error in our IE11/Outlook2013 environment. [Our add-in](https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104380691) has been tested by the Office store team too, no issues.

Can someone explain how exactly Outlook 2013 is determining the "add-in unresponsiveness" and how we can figure out what is going wrong? Our add-in continues to work fine for the user but the error is always there.

More environment details:

[IE11](https://www.evernote.com/l/AGPMw5fO0dpKrIqBZWbE-QZ4IKq6VEOtGKA)and [Outlook 2013](https://www.evernote.com/l/AGMDgB50DHZDz7WA3k47QEVGTUkpikLgEw0) and [Windows 7](https://www.evernote.com/l/AGPC6lA_bSBM-blpSXvtoSJdE4MBQRul0cs)

An update. We've reduced the size of the initially loaded JS code by 2x (~900kb now), optimized loaded css too but Outlook 2013 still flags the very first add-in load sometimes (not consistently). Later on the error may go away. Not sure what else we can do here, it seems Outlook's way of measuring add-in's responsiveness is not perfect or buggy.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have the version information of Outlook 2013 that is causing this issue? 

What happens when the user just clicks the close on the dialog? Does the app just work fine? 

This will be hard to diagnose without a repro, but we can ask the developers what can cause this.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for your response. If you click the Outlook 2013 link you'll see a screenshot with the exact Outlook version, Windows 7 link shows what kind of a computer it is. i7 2.67GHz, 16G RAM does not seem slow. I also added our Office store app link. Our app has been tested in all environments and we have not encountered this error yet. Yes our app continues to work even with this error/alert but our client wont release our add-in to its users with this error. We need to figure out a way to fix this. Is there anything we could optimize?

Comment: The repro is not consistent? (which would make it hard for us to check if there is a bug?) Outlook's way of getting around this, is that these values are adjustable via RegKey and Group Policy (as mentioned here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219429.aspx#BKMK_Overriding) 

I can follow up with the developer owners for this to see anymore, but it would be worth it to try applying those reg keys and see if that stops this from happening. Specifically the "Specify alert interval for web extensions" Group Policy. or AlertInterval RegKey.

Comment: To further update, since this seems to be a problem with a particular customer's computer (or subset of computers), the customer may want to open a support case with Microsoft. And Support can dig into and try to understand why these computers repro this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Followed up with a developer. This indicates that your Add-In used more than 90% of the CPU in 15 seconds checked in 5 second intervals. Basically the app used too much of the computer's CPU. As the error indicates the user can just click the "x" and continue if they want, it is an ignorable error.

Is your app doing something that consumes a lot of CPU? It could also be the case the user is just on a slow computer? It may be the latter due to the fact that only this user has the problem.

For more details on performance limits check: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219429.aspx#BKMK_Overriding

These values are adjustable by regKey as well.

Comment: This is something you wouldn't notice in any documentation. Good to know. +1